# After creating source in stripe using stripe.js stripeResponseHandler function is not calling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, stripe-payments, payment

i have been trying from last 4 hours but this problem is not solving. i am creating charge for bitcoin using stripe.js.

the charge is creating successfully but after creating the charge the function "stripeResponseHandler" is not calling. I have try so many things but it no avail. 
my code is

```
stripe.createSource({
      type: 'bitcoin',
      amount: 1000,
      currency: 'usd',
      owner: {
        email: 'jenny.rosen@example.com',
      },
    }, stripeResponseHandler);

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
        console.log("here");
        console.log(status);
        console.log(response);

}
```

Nothing is printing on the console. I have checked my dashboard events and logs and the charge is creating.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled to extract the data from Stripe's create source response. This worked for me:

```
stripe.createSource({type: 'card', owner: {
  name: 'Jenny Rosen'
}}).then(function(result, err) {
  console.log(result.source)
  console.log(err.source)
});
```

If you need to extract the Id, replace result.source with result.source.id and so on. Here is [the API reference.](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=node#source_object)

Also, make sure you enable the **View test data** switch and use [Stripe's test cards](https://stripe.com/docs/testing). You can find all the calls to your stripe account under **Developers** > **Logs** in your dashboard.